# No line number in Log4j trace level

Tags: java, log4j

This is my **log4j.properties**:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{3}:%L - %m%n
```

%L is the line number.

In my class I have this:

```
LOGGER.trace("Connection: " + connection);
```

But in console i don't see line (it's just "?"):

```
23.12.2014 05:57:26 TRACE Mysql:? - Connection: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@46116f2
```

If i use LOGGER.info or something else, besides .trace, it works fine.

Who knows why?

Comment: What is the version of log4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40255) which got fixed in the later versions. I verified with 1.2.15 and it works as expected.